# How to define a JSON schema that has variable required properties

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I would like to know if I can define a JSON schema (draft 2019-09) that requires at least one of many properties possible for an object, and some times multiple of those properties. I already know of allOf, anyOf, oneOf, and dependantrequried but just can't figure out how to use them in the way I want.

I have an object with four keys:

- `amount`
- `productId`
- `invoiceId`
- `jwt`

I have the follow requirements:

- `amount`, `productId`, and `invoiceId` can not be in the object together
- `invoiceId` must have `jwt`
- `jwt` may be alone or with `amount` or `product`
- must have at least one of the four keys in the object will respecting the above rules.

I have tried this schema, this works in most cases excpet when `jwt` is alone:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "amount": {"type": "number"},
    "productId": {"type": "string"},
    "invoiceId": {"type": "string"},
    "jwt": {"type": "string"},
  },
  "dependantRequried": {
    "invoiceId": ["jwt"]
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {"required": ["amount"]},
    {"required": ["productId"]},
    {"required": ["invoiceId"]},
  ]
}
```

Adding `{"required": ["jwt"]}` to "oneOf" array means that it fails when `invoiceId` and `jwt` are together.

expected results:

| json | isValid |
| --- | --- |
| `{"amount": 1}` | true |
| `{"amount": 1, "jwt": "jwt-test"}` | true |
| `{"productId": "prod-1"}` | true |
| `{"productId": "prod-1", "jwt": "jwt-test"}` | true |
| `{"invoiceId": "inv-1", "jwt": "jwt-test"}` | true |
| `{"jwt": "jwt-test"}` | true |
| `{"invoiceId": "inv-1"}` | false |
| `{"amount": 1, "productId": "prod-1"}` | false |
| `{"amount": 1, "productId": "prod-1", "jwt": "jwt-test"}` | false |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options.

#### 1. `if`/`then`/`else`

Instead of using `required` directly, try an `if`/`then` construct to forbid the other properties when one is present.

```
{
  // ...,
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "if": {"required": ["amount"]},
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "productId": false,
          "invoiceId": false,
        }
      },
      "else": false
    },
    // repeat for productId and invoiceId
    {
      "properties": {
          "amount": false,
          "productId": false,
          "invoiceId": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The first subschema says that if `amount` is present in the instance, the other two cannot have values, which is a roundabout way of saying they're disallowed.  Repeat this for the other two properties.

The last one covers the case where none of them are present.

#### 2. Just use `properties`

This basically does the same thing, but some may consider it less readable.  It's a style question, really.

```
{
  // ...,
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
          "amount": true,
          "productId": false,
          "invoiceId": false
      }
    },
    // repeat for productId and invoiceId
    {
      "properties": {
          "amount": false,
          "productId": false,
          "invoiceId": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the first subschema allows only the `amount` property.  Again, repeat this for the other two properties, and have the same last case.

---

You also want to use `anyOf` instead of `oneOf`.  `oneOf` would work, but it's a more intensive check.  Some implementations can shortcut and not evaluate the other subschemas once they've found one that works.  For a `oneOf`, though, all subschemas must always be checked.  Since we've arranged this so that only one of these can be valid, `anyOf` will do.

Lastly, you also have a typo: `dependantRequried` -> `dependentRequired`.

You can test these out at https://json-everything.net/json-schema.

Comment: I was able to use the first approach and build it to meet my use case. Thanks for the help!